# Load processing.js sketch after window is fully loaded with innerHTML?

Tags: jquery, processing.js

My processing.js sketch has a size() call that depends on the window being loaded as it grabs the size of a div. 50% of the time, the sketch loads before the CSS kicks in, so the sketch doesn't have the right size. I figure the best way to combat this is to load it in a window.onload function, but canvas doesn't seem to like being invoked by innerHTML. How could I pump some canvas with a processing sketch into a div on command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it's not so much canvas not working as it's Processing.js not looking for DOM insertions for canvas to load sketches; it only does a general pass for sketches to load on DOM content loaded. Since you want your sketch injected after that, you can either trigger a reparse (by calling Processing.reload(), which will reset everything, so if you have other sketches on the same page that should not be reset, don't use that) or you can call

```
var sourceList = ['file1.pde','file2.pde','...',...];
var canvas = document.querySelector("#mycanvas");
Processing.loadSketchFromSources(canvas, sourceList);
```

specifically for the one sketch whenever it's safe to inject it into the page.